# Fantasy Soccer (English Premier League) datasets

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for fantasy soccer datasets for the English Premier League -- points for each player for each match day this season, ideally from DraftKings.

If someone knows a good resource where to get the data, or if someone has collected the data and is willing to share it, I would really appreciate it.

I just started with fantasy soccer couple of weeks ago and wrote a script for the start in order to collect a bunch of data from different sources (e.g., injuries, suspensions, fantasy points, team standings etc.). I wanted to share it with you in hope that it might be useful for one or the other: https://github.com/rasbt/datacollect/tree/master/collect_fantasysoccer I also have a tool to merge the data tables based on "normalized" player names that I will upload it soon, too.

### Edit:

Right now, there is a lot of noise in my model, however, it was sufficient to win so far. You can see that the prediction and actual outcome (in the plot below) are a little bit off, but it is quite fun so far and will become more accurate over time as I collect more data:

The plot is for match day 20:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like what you are working on!  Looks like about the same time I was adding a Github project/repo to start sharing R code for analysis we were motivated to try out.  I've not added much code to Github yet but hope to in the near future with data for examples.

Another site to look at - you have more more expertise inputting data of the sites than I do, is the primary EPL site and [fantasy game](http://fantasy.premierleague.com).  My older son and I have been playing that one for many years and like the mix of data made available.  Much more than other sites.  We also manually compile some data on specific areas of interest such as shots (an associated goalie data).  Every good analytics article you read on the web or in print always gives a few more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @geogaffer! I just started playing on DraftKings a couple of weeks ago and my prediction models worked quite well so far. I will keep at it, and if I have more data, I will also share my code and models on GitHub! Meanwhile, the EPL fantasy game website looks like another good resource for data! The model is not that accurate yet but becomes better every matchday as I collect more data. I will attach a plot of my last prediction